What is the value of air anisotropy?
I am calculating a jet - gas nozzle and to calculate it, I need to know the anisotropy of the air, what is it equal to?

In this formula, the desired value is under the letter n
A source:Engine

Please quote the equation you are using that contains this variable.

@OrganicMarble completed the question

Which of those variables represents "air anisotropy"? Also, when you post an image, you should say where it came from, unless you created it.

The linked text calls $n$ "isentropic index", not "anisotropy".

What you are calling "air anisotropy" (I have not heard it called that before) represented by "n" in your equation is usually called "gamma" or "k" in the West.
It is the ratio of specific heats, and its value depends on what working fluid you are dealing with.
References Wikipedia, NASA
Just as an example, here is a table from Sutton 7th edition showing variance in gamma / k based on fluid properties.

Therefore, your question asking for a value cannot be answered unless you provide information on the fluid properties. The Wikipedia article gives values for some more or less randomly chosen fluids.
